# Index out of bound error varies when it shows

Tags: java, arrays

I keep getting an Index out of bounds error when i run this program periodically. I notice it more when I enter a higher starting percentage like 80+. I know it has to do with the shotsMade `ArrayList`. But i am not sure what to do to correct it. Thanks.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myGameCounter = 1;  
        List<Integer> shotsMade = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        shotsMade.add(0);
        System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int percent = input.nextInt();


        //Game #1
        System.out.println("Game " + myGameCounter + ":");
        Random r = new Random();
        myGameCounter++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
            if (in) {
            shotsMade.set(0, shotsMade.get(0)+1);
            System.out.print("In" + " ");
            }
            else {
            shotsMade.add(0);
            System.out.print("Out" + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Free throws made: " + shotsMade.get(0) + " out of 10");
            //Game #2
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Game" + myGameCounter + ":");
        myGameCounter++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
            if (in) {
            shotsMade.set(1, shotsMade.get(1)+1);
            System.out.print("In" + " ");
            }
            else {
            shotsMade.add(0);
            System.out.print("Out" + " ");
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Free throws made: " + shotsMade.get(1) + " out of 10");
            //Game #3
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Game" + myGameCounter + ":");
        myGameCounter++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
            if (in) {
            shotsMade.set(2, shotsMade.get(2)+1);
            System.out.print("In" + " ");
            }
            else {
            shotsMade.add(0);
            System.out.print("Out" + " ");
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Free throws made: " + shotsMade.get(2) + " out of 10");
            //Game #4
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Game" + myGameCounter + ":");
        myGameCounter++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
            if (in) {
            shotsMade.set(3, shotsMade.get(3)+1);
            System.out.print("In" + " ");
            }
            else {
            shotsMade.add(0);
            System.out.print("Out" + " ");
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Free throws made: " + shotsMade.get(3) + " out of 10");
            //Game #5
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Game" + myGameCounter + ":");
        myGameCounter++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
            if (in) {
            shotsMade.set(4, shotsMade.get(4)+1);
            System.out.print("In" + " ");
            }
            else {
            shotsMade.add(0);
            System.out.print("Out" + " ");
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Free throws made: " + shotsMade.get(4) + " out of 10");

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Summary:");


  }//main        



    public static boolean tryFreeThrow(int percent) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int number = r.nextInt(100);
        if (number > percent){ 
         return false;
        }
        return true;
    }






}//class
```

Comment: care showing stacktrace or Exception causing line?

Comment: TIP: If the (max) number of throws is fixed, use a plain array.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:1, Size: 1  at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck<ArrayList,java:635> at java.util.ArrayList.get<ArrayList.java:411> at Test.man<Test.java.37> However it varies one run could go fine all 5 games, the next could do 3 games and the Index error be on Index 3 or 4.

Comment: The code for each game looks so similar, it could be moved into its own function or class.

Comment: @ambigram_maker using a plain array will I still be able to add to the array the same way and call the elements the same?

Comment: @andrbmgi I tried that but since the shotsMade.get index has to change each game it didnt function when I tried that.

Comment: Well, _go figure_! Figure it out. Using a plain array is simpler because the index of the elements doesn't change because there is no `add` method, u can only `set` elements.

Comment: @ambiram_maker So what you are recomending is making an Array such as int[] shotsMade = new int[5], then i would need to create a count per game that the total would be initalized to shotsMade [0] for first game, shotsMade[1] for 2nd etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not run the code, but it looks like if you run the game and get 10 In's, followed by a In on the second game then you never add a second entry to the array list..

Therefore the second game will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException when you call

```
shotsMade.set(1, shotsMade.get(1)+1);
```

in the second game

Answer (score 0):

When you `add` to shotsMade you will add another entry at the end. If you `set` you will change one position:

so

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 -> add(0) -> 0 1 2 3 0
> 0 1 2 3 -> set(2, 0) -> 0 1 0 3
> ```

So if you want to call `shotsMade.get(1)` you need to miss once first because if you hit you use `set` and your list doesn't expand and is too short.